# Direct reply notifications on older android versions

Tags: android, notifications

Is is possible to make notifications with direct reply on older Android versions? If it is possible can someone explain it to me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's only available in Android 7 as far as I know. You could use the method that Whatsapp uses if you want to

Comment: And what is the method that Whatsapp uses? Is it the same as Google Hangouts?

Comment: I don't use Google Hangouts but Whatsapp uses a pop-up like activity once you press the "Reply" button in the notification: https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ampercent.com%2Fwp%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2FReply-to-first-message.png&f=1

Answer (score -1):

No, it's not possible on the older version of android.